# Unit-testing shared library with Makefile

Tags: unit-testing, makefile

I'm writing a shared library, which I have written a unit-testing executable.
I would like to create a target in the Makefile which will initiate the the testing routine.

The unit-testing executable is linked to the library that's created a moment ago.

When running the executable within Makefile, I get

```
./starttest: error while loading shared libraries: libllist.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Which way is better to approach this issue ?**

1. defining `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from within the Makefile like this ?

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(CURDIR)/lib
2. force the user to install the library before running the tests ?
3. Don't start unit-testing from Makefile, the user will do it by himself.

or maybe I missed something and there's even a better way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use option #1, if all you want is for the unit tests to be invoked through the makefile.  Definitely option #2 should not be used, and I don't like option #3 much either.

A fourth alternative is to build your unit test program using the `-rpath` linker option to encode the location of the shared library into the unit test program.  For example if you're using GCC this would be: `-Wl,-rpath=$(CURDIR)`.  This allows the unit test to be invoked from the command line, without needing LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc. to be set.

This isn't a good idea for final binaries (to encode your build directory into them) but it's fine for unit test binaries that you won't be using outside your build directory anyway.

Comment: Actually I figured this one 10 minutes ago (the -rpath technique) but I decided to keep the question to see more options.

Comment: There are only so many ways a program can use to find a shared library.  The only option available that's not already considered above is to modify the system's default list of directories to look at.  This would require admin privileges to be updated for every workspace, so it's obviously a non-starter.